# VBA - Copy -pasting columns with blanks cells

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to write a code to copy values in different column from one sheet to another(Both sheet have same headers) 
There are few columns which I can simply copy and paste using the below code.
But for the column which have blank column in between what would be the best way to copy these column.
I know this can be done using variable , I am curious to find out if this can be done without using any variable.

Also , is there any smarter way to write a code to copy all the columns in one go (with or without declaring any variables)[image]

```
Sheets("type 1").Select
Cells.Find(What:=" Netherland ").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("type 2").Select
Cells.Find(What:=" Netherland ").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: You could do it in one go if your columns were in the same order in both sheets. Is that a possibility? Btw you could do this with formulae.

Comment: @SJR Thanks for the reply, But the headers are not in order , and I prefer VBA coding reason The data set is too large and the pattern often change .Also I want to use Macro as want to do further processing after this step.

Comment: You after you find the headers, you could just set the destination column to = to the value of the source headers

Comment: My next question is: why are you doing this at all? If your data are on one sheet why transfer the same info to another?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
Worksheets("type 2").Columns(Worksheets("type 2").Find("*Netherland*").Column).Value _
= Worksheets("type 1").Columns(Worksheets("type 1").Find("*Netherland*").Column).Value
```

You could make this a lot cleaner by setting the column numbers to variables and just using them instead of the actual line to find them, but this doesn't require any additional variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `SpecialCells` property to include the entire column, including any empty cells that appear between the first and last cells.

So where you have:

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Instead use something like:

```
.Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
```

Though you'll have to change the range references to suit your project.